# SQL storing strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to saving strings in database. Each string has different size from 1 to N. I think that limit will be about 10000, maybe more. nvarchar(MAX) will be best way to resolve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `SQL Server 2005` and later, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is the best way to store strings that can be more than `4000` characters long.

It's the only way recommended for `SQL Server 2005` and higher, though it still supports `TEXT` columns for backward compatibility.

Note, that you cannot create an index on an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column.

To use the index, create a computed column and use it in index searches. It may serve as an efficient coarse filter:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INT NOT NULL, mytext NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, mytext_index AS CAST(mytext AS NVARCHAR(450))

CREATE INDEX ix_foo_mytext (mytext_index)

SELECT  *
FROM    mytext
WHERE   mytext_index LIKE 'L%'
```

Comment: Over 4000 since we are talking about nvarchar

Comment: Sure, missed it. Fixing in a hurry :)

Answer (score 1):

nvarchar is correct if they are unicode (or other non-7-or-8-bit strings). If they are for instance ASCII latin-1 text (sufficient in many cases), varchar(MAX) will save space.